# Back-transforming contrast lstrends results in r

Tags: r, lme4-nlme, back-transformation, test-for-trend

I calculated a linear mixed model using the packages lme4 and lsmeans with the lmer-function, where i have one dependent variable rv and the interacting factors treatment, time, age and race. I'm interested in the ***response variable change over time***, that's why i use the ***lstrends***-function. So far so good. The problem is, i have to square root the response variable in order to fit the model properly. But the pairs-function only gives out a response to the square root of the rv, hard to interpret!

So i tried to back-transform the response variable after pairs:

```
model.lmer <- lmer(sqrt(rv) ~ treat*time*age*race + (1|individual), data=mydata)
model.lst <- lstrends(model.lmer, ~treat | age*race , var = "time", type="response")
pairs(mouse.lst, type="response")
```

This obviously doesn't work, as stated by the package itself:

```
# Transformed response
sqwarp.rg <- ref.grid(update(warp.lm, sqrt(breaks) ~ .))
summary(sqwarp.rg)

# Back-transformed results - compare with summary of 'warp.rg'
summary(sqwarp.rg, type = "response")

# But differences of sqrts can't be back-transformed
summary(pairs(sqwarp.rg, by = "wool"), type = "response")

# We can do it via regrid
sqwarp.rg2 <- regrid(sqwarp.rg)
summary(sqwarp.rg2)  # same as for sqwarp.rg with type = "response"
pairs(sqwarp.rg2, by = "wool")
```

Anybode got an idea how to solve this particular problem? Thanks in advance!

edit1:

It could look like the following code:

```
summary(pairs(lsmeans(rg.regrid, ~ treat | race*age, trend="time")), type="response")
```

The problem is, i can't alter the reference grid for lstrends, just for lsmeans, because the first argument in lstrends or lsmeans with trend="time" requires the linear mixed effect model (model.lmer) intead of just the reference grid like in lsmeans, without the trend-argument... That's probably why i can't back-transform the data with

edit2: This here sums up my problem pretty well:

```
model.sqrt <- lmer(sqrt(rv) ~ time*treat*race*age, data=mydata)
rg <- ref.grid(model.sqrt)
rg.regrid <- regrid(rg)
summary(pairs(lsmeans(rg.regrid, ~treat | race*age*time), type = "response"))
```

works perfectly.

```
summary(pairs(lsmeans(rg.regrid, ~treat | race*age, trend="time"), type = "response"))
```

Gives the following error:

```
Error in summary(pairs(lsmeans(rg.regrid, ~treat | race * age, trend = "time"),  : 
error in evaluating the argument 'object' in selecting a method for function 'summary': Error in data[[var]] : subscript out of bounds
```

How to avoid the error and still be able to back-transform my data?

edit3:

```
model <- lme(sqrt(dv) ~ time*treat*race*age, random=~1|individual, data=mydata, weights=varPower(0.19, form = ~time|individual), method="ML")

lsms <- summary(pairs(model, ~treat | time*race*age, at=list(time=4))))$estimate

slome <- summary(pairs(lstrends(model, ~treat | race*age, var="time")))$estimate
slose <- summary(pairs(lstrends(model, ~treat | race*age, var="time")))$SE

for(i in 1:4){
    eslo[i] <- 2 * lsms[i] * slome[i]
    ese[i] <- abs(2*lsms[i]) * slose[i]
    }
```

i = 1 is race1 at age1;

i = 2 is race1 at age2;

i = 3 is race2 at age1;

i = 4 is race2 at age2;

slose: slope-SE from lstrends for sqrt(dv)-difference between treated and untreated group

slome: slope from lstrends for sqrt(dv)-difference per time between treated and untreated group

eslo and ese: estimated slope and se for dv-difference per time between treated and untreated group

Comment: Although asked in the context of R code, this is a statistical question (& hence on topic) IMO.

Comment: That's true, but i'd like to have a specific answer for r, how to back-transform square root dependent variables within lstrends, and not just lsmeans how all the tutorials show it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've thought about this some now, and I'm realizing we can sort this out. Let $t$ denote your `time` variable, $r$ denote your `rv` response variable, and let $y=\sqrt r$ be the response you actually used in the model. Then
$$dr/dt = dy^2/dt =2y\cdot dy/dt$$
and note that `lstrends` can calculate values of $dy/dt$. It follows that
$$ SE(dr/dt) \approx |2y|\cdot SE(dy/dt) $$
Note also that $y$ depends on $t$ (as well as other variables), so you need to take due care and probably include some specific key values of $t$ in the reference grid (use the `at` argument).

Once you do that, you can use `summary(lsmeans())` to calculate a data frame `lsms` whose least-squares means estimate the needed values of $y$; and use`summary(lstrends())` to create a data frame `slopes` whose least-squares means are the corresponding estimates of $dy/dt$. Finally, the estimated slopes $dr/dt$ will be `2 * lsms$lsmean * slopes$lsmean`, and estimates of $SE(dr/dt)$ will be `abs(2 * lsms$lsmean) * slopes$SE`.

In principle, this idea could be incorporated in the `lstrends` function (e.g., as its way of supporting `type = "response"` situations). I'll poke around with that and see how easily this feature could be added.

Comment: Using the pairs comment, i already to a sub-group analysis (young race 1, old race1, young race2, old race2, having 1 slope and SE for each combination of race and age). So the pairs-comment, compares the slope of dv over time for the how you call them specific key values of age and race. Instead of having a slope for all dv over time-values, i'm having now with your method different slopes for each timepoint, right? So the slope would not be just "2.4 +/- 0.8", but something like "0.3*t +/- 0.5*(sqrt(t))"?

So i need to add specifc t-value, or can i get a slope in function of the time?

Comment: I was talking about specific **time** values. If you want to work on the response scale, the trends are not linear: the slope is different at each time, and if you want numerical estimates, you have to say which time(s) to use.

Comment: I edited my entry post and calculated the estimated values for the timepoint time=4. Is the calculation the right interpretation of your solution mentioned above? And is it right to use the lsmeans from the pairs() argument as i did in my calculations?

Comment: It is not right to use the pairs results. Basically I think I'd better try to get lstrends to do the right thing and send it to you. This'll take a day or two at least.

Comment: Ok, thanks a lot!! I'm also struggeling getting the confidence levels out of the back-transformed lstrends, but the new lstrends would sure save me a lot of trouble!